# Redirecting to error 404 from custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I have a wordpress multilingual site, and for that I used wpml for translations. Also have 2 custom post types + products which were created by woocommerce. Now one of the custom post types works only for one language which isn't default language and in other languages page is redirected to 404 page. I've tried to save Settings->Permalinks page but no success.

Comment: When you check the custom post type (just edit a post in it) there your should be a box which says "Make this post type translatable". Did you check that?

Comment: Yes, right now I do that but again redirects to error 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found s aolution for my problem. In WPML->Translation Management this "Translate custom posts slugs (via WPML String Translation)" option was checked and that caused my problem, I unchecked that and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try switch to All Language in WPML Header and then save permalinks settings page. Worked for us for post categories with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case switching the Permalink (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php) from Post to Plain and back solved the issue!